# NSTableView messup with other controlls on mainView

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have added `NSTableView` on my `mainWindow` and then I want 2 button (up arrow and down arrow) to add on `mainWindow` but they will overlap the tableview.
But when `NSTableView` loads data or scrolls my button hides.

Please help me out how can I achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take advantage of Sizing and/or autolayout.

You must have not set for those buttons. Check for buttons and for table view.

When you draw tableview you will see blue helper line, that guides you to use properly. And draw table my checking it should meet top, left and right blue lines.

For button put them in bottom and check for line below them as well as from left side.

[image]